# Install wordpress using composer in a specific language

Tags: language, composer

I'm using composer to automatically deploy wordpress on a ubuntu-server. Additionally, I need to install the german language pack. I learned that there are some guys who create composer-packages from the wordpress.org files. Using the following composer.json I get wordpress with german language pack:

```
{
    "repositories": [{
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://wp-languages.github.io"
    }],
    "require": {
        "johnpbloch/wordpress": "4.6",
        "koodimonni-language/core-de_de": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "wordpress-install-dir": "wp",
        "dropin-paths": {
            "wp/wp-content/languages": ["vendor:koodimonni-language"],
            "wp/wp-content/languages/plugins/": ["vendor:koodimonni-plugin-language"],
            "wp/wp-content/languages/themes/": ["vendor:koodimonni-theme-language"]
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, that wordpress itself is still in english. Is it possible to set it automatically to german, so that I don't have to do this manually for every site in the adminpanel?

Answer (score 1):

The current WP versions expose interface for this and store locale in `WPLANG` option. Depending on your tools you could set it up during your spin up process (for example with WP CLI).

Older version used `WPLANG` *constant* in `wp-config.php`. I think it should still work on a fresh install (if you don't have *option* set up) so you could include it in whatever process you use to write `wp-config.php`.